# Hide InfoBox When Marker is in Cluster

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer, infobox

I've come to notice that a [infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) does not seem to disappear when the marker goes into a [cluster](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer).  Is there any already made way to make infoboxes disappear when the marker goes into a cluster then?  If not, any suggestions on how I would do this?  I was trying to find out how to get all current markers that are clustered, but I've had no luck.

Each marker has an info box made specifically for that marker.

Thanks for any help you can give in advance!

**Locations array example:**

```
var locations = [
    ['<div class="infomarkerdiv"><a href="index.php?p=JTLgRad15x8=&d=20150616041300"><div class="profile-pic-find" style="background-image: url(/bin/images/cars/2-1.jpg);"></div><div class="name"> Honda Civic</div></a></div>', 39.11342293092857, -77.8597175, 1, 2],
];
```

**Some of my main code:**

```
var marker, i;
var markers = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: theMap
    });

    markers.push(marker);



    var myOptions = {
        content: locations[i][0],
        boxClass: 'infobox',
        closeBoxURL: "",
        pane: "floatPane"
    };

    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);

    ib.open(theMap, marker);



}


var markers = markers; //some array;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
}

theMap.fitBounds(bounds);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
    //console.log(MarkerClusterer(getTotalMarkers()));
});


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
    ib.open(theMap, this);
});

var clusterStyles = [{
    textColor: 'white',
    url: 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/m1.png',
    height: 55,
    width: 53
}, {
    textColor: 'white',
    url: 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/m1.png',
    height: 55,
    width: 53
}, {
    textColor: 'white',
    url: 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/m1.png',
    height: 55,
    width: 53
}];
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(theMap, markers, mcOptions);
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  Sounds like you have individual InfoBoxes for each marker, how do you create them/access them?

Comment: Just added some code.  Each marker has an infobox made dynamically for it.  That data is given to the infobox via the my locations array.

Comment: There are multiple InfoBoxes being displayed on the map at once, just thought I'd put that out there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hide infowindow on markers which are inside marker cluster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415373/how-can-i-hide-infowindow-on-markers-which-are-inside-marker-cluster)

Comment: Except for the face I'm talking about infoboxes and not infowindows.  I will check that though.